# Difference between "and not ()" and "and (... not like ...)"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I receive completely different results from my query depending on where I put NOT. Can you please explain the difference?

Below is the first way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM [table]
 WHERE condition = 'N'
   AND (Category NOT LIKE '%str1%'
     OR Category NOT LIKE '%str2%'
     OR Category NOT LIKE '%str3%')
```

The second way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM [table]
 WHERE condition = 'N'
   AND NOT (Category LIKE '%str1%'
         OR Category LIKE '%str2%'
         OR Category LIKE '%str3%')
```

Both seem the same for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the operators within the parentheses to `AND`, if you add `NOT`, which will impact adversly all the terms within parentheses, such as

```
SELECT count(*) 
  FROM[table]
 WHERE condition = 'N'
   AND NOT (Category LIKE '%str1%'
        AND Category LIKE '%str2%'
        AND Category LIKE '%str3%')
```

*A OR B* equals *NOT ( A AND B )* in Boolean logic

Comment: If this is the case, is my first way correct. My idea is that I want the first condition (condition = 'N') and neither one of the conditions in the parentheses.

Comment: The idea is the one that I wrote above in the comment.

Comment: you can prefer either the first one or the one within the answer in order to make both queries return the same result @Yana .

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I need to check again the De Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to note that you can simplify this logic:

```
WHERE condition = 'N' AND
      Category NOT REGEXP 'str1|str2|str3'
```

This eliminates issues with parentheses and the placement of the `NOT`.

Comment: I work with Azure. This gives an error. Is REGEXP supported?

Comment: @Yana . . . No.  Your question is mistagged.